# arm64-v8a taking alot of MBs(16MB) on flutter apk what could be the reason?

Tags: flutter

I ran `flutter build apk analyze size` and when i checked, it seems `arm64-v8a` takes a lot of size(16MB) and this causes the app to have a total of 20MB, is there a reason to explain this?

Comment: you might be running the debug build, release build has comparatively lower size

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, Should i add --release to flutter build apk or is it just supposed to pick automatically if not set?

Comment: by default debug build is created, for release run the command flutter run --release

Comment: `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`

Comment: I changed my min sdk version from 26 to 21 and the app reduced from 21MB to 11MB and it worked like a charm!
Thank you all.